# Nest.js authentication with passport-local result in Error: Unknown authentication strategy "local"

Tags: typescript, authentication, nestjs, passport-local, nestjs-passport

I am new to Nest.js and currently trying to figure out how to get my authentication to run. I use passport-local and followed the tutorial on the offical Nest.js website, but I keep getting the error `Unknown authentication strategy "local"`. Here is my code as I dont have anything more to say (I left some services like user service out, as I think they do not have anything to do with the problem, but I can send them on request). This is my "first" real question (I asked some question when I was little some years ago). I hope this is not too much code, but I dont know how else to state my problem. I hope this is okay. Thanks for you help! :)

auth.module.ts:

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { PassportModule } from '@nestjs/passport';
import { UsersModule } from '../users/users.module';
import { AuthService } from './auth.service';
import { LocalStrategy } from './local.strategy';

@Module({ 
  imports: [UsersModule, PassportModule],
  providers: [AuthService, LocalStrategy]
})
export class AuthModule {}
```

local-auth.guard.ts:

```
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { AuthGuard } from '@nestjs/passport';

@Injectable()
export class LocalAuthGuard extends AuthGuard('local') {}
```

local.strategy.ts:

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core"
import { UnauthorizedException } from "@nestjs/common";
import { PassportStrategy } from "@nestjs/passport"
import { Strategy } from "passport-local"
import { AuthService } from "./auth.service"
@Injectable()
export class LocalStrategy extends PassportStrategy(Strategy) {
    constructor(private authService: AuthService) {
        super();
    }

    async validate(username: string, password: string): Promise<any> {
        const user = await this.authService.validateUser(username, password);
        if (!user) {
            throw new UnauthorizedException();
        }
        return user;
    }
}
```

app.module.ts:

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { AppController } from './app.controller';
import { AppService } from './app.service';

@Module({
  imports: [],
  controllers: [AppController],
  providers: [AppService],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

app.controller.ts

```
import { Controller, Get, Post, Request, UseGuards } from '@nestjs/common';
import { LocalAuthGuard } from '../auth/local-auth.guard';
import { AppService } from './app.service';

@Controller()
export class AppController {
  constructor(private readonly appService: AppService) {}

  @UseGuards(LocalAuthGuard)
  @Post('login')
  login(@Request() req): any {
    return req.user;
  }

  @Get('protected')
  getData() {
    return this.appService.getData();
  }
}
```

auth.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { UsersService } from '../users/users.service';

@Injectable()
export class AuthService {

    constructor (private userService: UsersService) {}

    async validateUser(username: string, password: string): Promise<any> {
        const user = await this.userService.existsUser(username);
        if (user && (user.password === password)) {
            const {password, username, ...rest} = user; 
            return rest;
        }
        return null;
    } 
}
```

user.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';

export type User = {
    id: number,
    name: string,
    username: string,
    password: string
}

@Injectable()
export class UsersService {
    private readonly users: User[] = [
        {
            id: 1,
            name: "testname",
            username: "cooluser",
            password: "admin"
        }
    ];

    async existsUser(username: string): Promise<User | undefined> {
        return this.users.find( (user) => {
            user.username === username;
        });
    }
}
```

users.module.ts

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { UsersService } from './users.service';

@Module({
    providers: [UsersService],
    exports: [UsersService]
})
export class UsersModule {}
```

Comment: Can you show your AuthService`?

Comment: Hi, I added it to my question above, because inline code was not working inside the comments.

Comment: Okay, can you add `UsersService` as well? Along with any of its dependencies

Comment: I added the UserService and Im not sure what You mean by dependencies, the UserService doesnt import anything, thank You for taking time to look through this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh! Your `AppMoule` needs to import your `AuthModule` so the passport strategy gets registered

Comment: When I do so i get the following error while starting the app:
`Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: Must use import to load ES Module: /home/.../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2015/core.mjs
`

Comment: You've imported `@Injectable()` from `@angular/core` instead of `@nestjs/common` in your `LocalStrategy`

Comment: What a silly mistake, it works now, ,thank You! But now I keep getting 401 Unauthorized even though the credentials are right, do You maybe know why?

Comment: @gabri2503 maybe, but there's too many possibilities to debug in just the comments. Please make a new question

Comment: Hm okay, i thought maybe You have an direct idea why it does not work, I dont know if it is worth opening a new question with the exact same code twice

Comment: Most likely you're not sending a `body` with `username` and `payload` fields. There's plenty of other SO questions and answers on getting a 401 back with a strategy though